# Get percentage of extraction with XZ Java for android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, xz

I am using the **[XZ Java](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html)** library to extract a `.xz` file on Android of size around 16MB. I am running the extraction/decompression code as an `AsyncTask` and so, I would like to see the percentage of extraction via the `onProgressUpdate(Integer ... values)` method.

My decompression code looks something like this.

```
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        String name = null;

        try {
            name = "my_archive.xz";
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_archive);//new FileInputStream(name); //
            FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("my_archive.sqlite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLabel);
            try {
                in = new XZInputStream(in);

                label.setText("Writing db file.");
                int size;
                while ((size = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buf,0,size);
                    progress++;
                    publishProgress(progress);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Input Stream error: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                // Close FileInputStream (directly or indirectly
                // via LZMAInputStream, it doesn't matter).
                in.close();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("LZMADecDemo: Cannot open " + name + ": "
                    + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);

        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.err.println("LZMADecDemo: Unexpected end of input on "
                    + name);
            System.exit(1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("LZMADecDemo: Error decompressing from "
                    + name + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

The `progress` variable should actually hold the percentage value. If anyone has worked with this library, and if you figured out an easy way to calculate the percentage of progress please help me out here.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get the size of the archive file using the `available()` method on the inputstream like below.

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_archive);
int fileSize = in.available();
```

And during extraction process, I calculated progress like below:

```
                int size;
                int counter=0;
                while ((size = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buf,0,size);
                    counter++;
                    progress = (int) (counter*100*1024/(double)fileSize);
                    publishProgress(progress);
                }
```

However, this doesn't result in the right progress for some reason. The progress goes upto 108% before its finished. I know I'm doing something wrong here, so please improve this answer with the right calculation.

Thanks